# MSSQL TO MySQL database Migration

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, mysql-workbench

I need a working tool for migrate DDL objects and data tables from MS SQL Server to MySQL. I checkout Database Migration Wizard in MySQLWorkBench 6.3,i have also tested with Ispirer tool (not free) and i can migrate only tables and data in tables but not views, store procedures and functions (maybe trigger not)..

In this MySQLWorkbench tools page : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-overview.html i found
"d.View objects are copied, and commented out if the source is not MySQL.
e.Stored Procedure and Function objects are copied, and commented out if the source is not MySQL."
So, i'm confused about why copy them and comment-out and not try to convert syntax? we know that database source is MSSQL so the syntax is different from mysql? I think it's impossible write mysql objects in MSSQL Server..no?

Thanks

Roby

Comment: Asking for a tool that rewrites stored routines is like asking for a tool that rewrites Python into PHP. I won't say it can't be done but it's unlikely there're many ongoing efforts. Whatever, this is not really an on-topic question, I'm afraid. (I didn't downvote, anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the syntax is different in MySQL. The conversion process is too complicated to do it automatically, however we gave the possibility to convert it manually. So if you want migrate those views/procedures, you must uncomment it and rewrite to MySQL compatible sql.